# "charset=UTF-8" sending mail in php

Tags: php, email, utf-8, character-encoding

My teacher asked us to be able to send email via our website. As I speak french, I tried using charset=UTF-8 in the header. It works well for mail address, headers, name with special char but not for the message of the mail itself...

I always receive message like **=?UTF-8?B?w6nDqSDDqMOoIMOgw6Agw6fDpw==?=**  .

Here is my php codes :

```
function contenuContactHTML(){
        echo '  <div id="contenu">
                    <h1> Formulaire de Contact </h1>
                    <form action="" method="post">
                        Votre Nom: <input type="text" name="prenomFormulaire"><br>
                        Votre E-mail: <input type="text" name="emailFormulaire"><br>
                        Sujet du message : <input type="text" name="sujetMailFormulaire"><br>
                        Votre Message: <textarea cols="40" rows="6" name="messageFormulaire" maxlength="4000" placeholder="message limité à 4000 cractères" required></textarea><br />
                        <input type="submit" name="envoieMailContact" value="Envoyer E-Mail">
                    </form>
                </div><!-- #contenu -->
            </div><!-- #centre --> ';
            envoieMail();       
    }

function envoieMail(){
        if(isset($_POST['envoieMailContact'])){ 
            $a = <i> My email adress</i>;
            $sujet = "=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($_POST['sujetMailFormulaire'])."?=";
            $de = "=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($_POST['emailFormulaire'])."?=";
            $messFormulaire = $_POST['messageFormulaire'];
            $message = "=?UTF-8?B?" . base64_encode($messFormulaire) . "?="; 
            $entete = "From: ". $de ."\r\n"
                      ."MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n" 
                      .'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' .'\r\n';
            mail($a, $sujet, $message, $entete);
            echo "<script language='JavaScript'>alert('Message envoyé !')</script>"; 
        }       
    }
```

Here is an example of the mail i receive : 
email adresse : mické@hotmail.com  
sujet (header) : on é pas des pigeaôns  
content of the mail (message) :  
=?UTF-8?B?YXplcnR5dWlvcF4kDQpxc2RmZ2hqa2xtw7nCtQ0Kd3hjdmJuLDs6DQrCsibDqSInKMKnw6ghw6fDoCkt?=

Comment: Your `Content-Type` header already specifies UTF-8. You shouldn't encode your message body like that.

Comment: $message = $_POST['messageFormulaire']; 
worked perfectly ! thanks ! was blocked on it since yesterday

Comment: The `=?UTF-8?B?...?=` encoding scheme comes from [RFC 2047](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2047) and is only used for SMTP headers. As mentioned above the encoding scheme for the message body is specified in the `Content-Type` header.